# Necessary and sufficient condition to vanish the complex Hessian

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, quadratic-forms

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}^n$, $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a $C^2$ function on $\Omega$. Let $H_f (a)$ be the complex Hessian of $f$ at $a\in \Omega$. In *Rudin's* book *Function Theory in Unit Ball $\mathbb{C}^n$*, it is claimmed that

$\langle H_f(a)b,b\rangle=0$ for all $a\in \Omega$ and for all $b\in \mathbb{C}^n$ if and only if each entry of $ H_f(a)$ is zero.

Now my question is how the condition $\langle H_f(a)b,b\rangle=0$ can imply that each entry of $ H_f(a)$ is zero.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: $f$ may not be real-valued. In that case, can we conclude that?

Comment: I expanded the expression and I got $\langle H x,y \rangle + \langle H y,x \rangle=0$. Now in order to get $H^* = H$ we must have $D_i \overline{D}_j f=D_i \overline{D}_j \overline{f}$, but for complex valued functions it may not be the case.

Comment: My apologies, I am incorrect, not sure what I was thinking.